# iPhone AIR app integration with a native Objective-C iPhone app

Tags: ios, air

I am beginning to port an existing Flash project to an iPhone AIR app for a client. The client already has an iPhone app created by an Objective-C developer. My client would like me to be able to incorporate my Flash elements into the Objective-C developer's existing iPhone app.

I'm not sure if this can be accomplished in some way, and if so, how. I'm guessing that giving the Objective-C developer my .ipa file would be useless. I'm also guessing that they would be unable to use my .swf files, but I'm not sure.

Does anyone have an idea as to how I might proceed? If you are able to point me in the right direction, I will gladly declare that your kung fu is the best!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with regular tools. I would go the other way around: try to reuse some of the Objective-C code inside your Air app, incorporating it into a Native Extension. Of course, depending on what the Objective-C code does, and on what your Air code does, it may or may not make sense.